# Android WebView new window null URLs on relative links

Tags: android, android-webview, webchromeclient

I have implemented a custom `WebView` with `setSupportMultipleWindows()` enabled. As such, I also have a custom `WebChromeClient` that overrides `onCreateWindow()`

For most uses, I was using the following snippet to retrieve the URL for a page in a new window (i.e. opened via `target:_blank`):

```
Message href = view.getHandler().obtainMessage();
view.requestFocusNodeHref(href);

String url = href.getData().getString("url");
```

There's null checks in place but I've removed them in the snippet above for simplicity's sake. Now the issue is that sometimes the data `Bundle` (returned via `getData()`) has a null URL for relative links (i.e. `href="/somepage"` instead of `href="https://www.example.com/somepage/"`).

So I searched on SO and found another possible solution:

```
WebView.HitTestResult result = view.getHitTestResult();
String url = result.getExtra();
```

However, that also returns null. If I get the type of the data using `result.getType()` it returns 0, which maps to `UNKNOWN_TYPE`.`

I am unsure why it is returning null for the aforementioned methods.
N.B. that if I disable support of multiple windows, those same links work just fine. Disabling such support, however, is not an option. **Is there another way to get the URL from within `onCreateWindow()`?**

Answer (score 1):

I haven't verified it, but you could try the following:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
            boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
        Logger.d(Constants.TAG, "onCreateWindow"+resultMsg);
        WebView targetWebView = new WebView(getActivity()); // pass a context
        targetWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                    Bitmap favicon) {
                handleWebViewLinks(url); // you can get your target url here
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }
        });
        WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
        transport.setWebView(targetWebView);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();
        return true;
    }
```

Hope this solves you problem! (=

Comment: That code it's working. Thanks for the help

Comment: Btw shouldOverrideUrlLoading works faster than onPageStarted.

Comment: for some reason this approach fails with `W/cr_AwContents: Popup WebView bind failed: no pending content.` right after `resultMsg.sendToTarget()` and `onPageStarted`/`shouldOverrideUrlLoading` doesn't get called. Can anyone understand why?